# Regex PHP remove certain keyword

Tags: php, regex

After viewing some answers on stackoverflow,

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
$img = array();
foreach( $result[0] as $img_tag)
{
    preg_match_all('/(title)=("[^"]*")/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
}

//print_r($img);
foreach ($img as $imgg)
 echo $imgg[2][0];
```

The above code finds img title, but however it return as `"Waterfall fountain"` instead of `Waterfall fountain`, notice there is `"`

what should i add in regex to remove `"`?

Thank you

Comment: Apparently not enough answers... the subject is beaten to fine ash. PHP has an HTML parser, which will do a better than a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the quotes outside of your brackets

```
preg_match_all('/(title)="([^"]*)"/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just move the `"` out of the capturing group:

```
'/(title)="([^"]*)"/i'
```

Comment: If you are dealing with legacy code that doesn't surround attributes with quotes, use this: `'/(title)="?([^" ]*)"?/i'` It also works if the quoted value does NOT contain a space

Answer (score 1):

Move the quotes outside of your brackets.

Check this :

```
preg_match_all('/(title)="([^"]*)"/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML Parser and this XPath to get all titles of img elements:

```
//img/@title
```

Example with [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xp->query('//img/@title') as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->nodeValue;
}
```

Further readings:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+DOM

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are making the `"` part of the match that is remembered. You can put the quotes outside the parenthesis:

```
preg_match_all('/(title)="([^"]*)"/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses in a regular expression make a capturing group, which control what get stored in `$img[$img_tag]`. Your group included the quotes: `("[^"]*")`. If you don't want the quotes, just move them outside the group: `"([^"]*)"`